# Kdump can't reboot using 'echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger'

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, crash, dump

I can reload kernel by using 'kexec -e', that means the configuration of my kernel should be correct. However the kernel can't automatically reboot after crashes. The output of command 'kdump-config show' shows the environment is correct.

```
RAMDISK$ kdump-config show
USE_KDUMP:        1
KDUMP_SYSCTL:     kernel.panic_on_oops=1
KDUMP_COREDIR:    /var/crash
crashkernel addr: 0xf000000
current state:    ready to kdump

kernel link: 

kexec command:
  /sbin/kexec -p --command-line="BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.1 root=UUID=4989514c-5622-4cd7-9b75-f0e07f7c6f84 ro initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet kgdboc=ttyS0,115200 irqpoll maxcpus=1 nousb" --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-3.2.1 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.1
RAMDISK$ 
RAMDISK$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.1 root=UUID=4989514c-5622-4cd7-9b75-f0e07f7c6f84 ro initrd=/install/initrd.gz crashkernel=256M quiet kgdboc=ttyS0,115200
RAMDISK$
```

The original kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64 build-in by debian 7.9 can work with kdump without any problem. 
Can anyone figure out what's wrong to my kernel, or the error log when kdump is working?

Comment: is CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ enabled in your kernel ? also are you echoing with root privileges ?

Comment: yes, CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ is enabled, or my system will not crash when I ‘’echo c ‘’to it.

Comment: what does this print "cat /proc/sys/kernel/panic" if its zero set to some value, say 1 if you want restart after 1 second of crash detection (echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/panic) alternatively you can use sysctl -w to set it as well.

Comment: the value prints 0, I set 1 to it, but the system still not reboot after crash

Comment: After crash, the screen prints the stack info and the value of registers. The last line is "[1] more>", followed by a flashing cursor.

Comment: strange, do you have a watchdog ? if yes could you try the application from here https://www.av8n.com/computer/htm/kernel-lockup.htm at bottom, keep it running in background and then force a crash and see if it restarts. Also probably try setting panic value to be something more just to check like 10 or more.

Comment: @PrabhakarLad sorry, I don't have a watchdog for my computer.